# How use MouseEventArgs in timertick?

Tags: c#, events, timer, mouseevent, eventargs

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

       MouseEventArgs m=e as MouseEventArgs;
        if (m.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dfgdf");
        }
}
```

It dont work
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseEventArgs` are, as stated by their name, arguments that come from mouse events. (such as `MouseDown` or `MouseUp`)

Each `Event` has his own `EventAgs`. Therefore, you can't use `MouseEventArgs` in your `Timer.Tick` event.

Here is the [EventArgs class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/system.eventargs(v=vs.100).aspx).